# I get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server" every time I log in

Tags: arch-linux, login, networkmanager

I use Arch Linux.

Every time I logged on, a browser window popped up on its own showing an error message. I did not open the browser, and I didn't go to the website by clicking a link.

The message says

> ### Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> *Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) Server at nmcheck.gnome.org Port 80*

The message looks like this:

[image: this is what it looks like]

I don't know what kind of permission I am lacking here (I am new to Linux).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: We are not understanding what the question here is. Are you _supposed_ to have permission to access to that website/URL? Did you encounter it while trying to follow a link from some other website? What have you (re)searched and/or tried already to try to resolve the issue? (And please edit your original question to include these details so others can quickly see them; do not simply reply in comments.)

Comment: I'm get the same error message, observing only since today morning. Although I'm connected to the internet, the WiFi icon is showing a question mark, and I get a popup showing the page http://nmcheck.gnome.org/ (as per the screenshot above), which seems to be down. I'm using Gnome on Manjaro.

Comment: What are you trying to login to?

Answer (score 8):

NetworkManager can optionally make an automatic connectivity check to `http://nmcheck.gnome.org/check_network_status.txt`. If it gets back the text `NetworkManager is online`, it assumes there is internet connectivity.

If a *different* answer is received (e.g. a redirect or other HTTP error code), then it assumes it's because the network you're currently connected to has a *captive portal*-style authentication requirement, and so it displays what it received in a window, with a title "Hotspot Login".

According to [NetworkManager.conf reference documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html) the connectivity check is not enabled by default, but your distribution may have different defaults, or you may have accidentally enabled it.

In your case, it seems that the check has been enabled, and the URI has somehow been truncated to just `http://nmcheck.gnome.org/`. That causes the `nmcheck.gnome.org` web server to return a `403 Forbidden` error, and NetworkManager does not try to analyze it any further: it just displays whatever it received as a "Hotspot Login" window.

If it's set by manual configuration, the settings would be in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, in the `[connectivity]` section. You could disable it by adding the line

```
enabled=false
```

in the same section (and adding the section header if it isn't there before). Or you could change the URI and the expected response too; see the link above for details if you're interested.

(Note: this configuration file can have sections named *connection*; those are not the same as *connectivity*. Be careful.)

If it's set programmatically through the D-Bus, the setting will be stored in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-intern.conf`.

You might find the setting in the GUI in this way:

> 1.)  Go to Settings app
> 2.)  Go to Privacy menu
> 3.)  On Connectivity tab, uncheck Connectivity Checking

Source: https://askubuntu.com/q/1070823/769591

Comment: My 2 cents: (1) by simply using `https` instead of `http` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` I got rid of this issue. I.e. a config with `uri=https://nmcheck.gnome.org/check_network_status.txt` should work (2) arch linux uses `http://ping.archlinux.org/nm-check.txt` by default (see `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity.conf`). However, this default will be overridden by configurations in `/etc/NetworkManager/`.